# How to generate EDMX file for EF6 in ASP.Net5 (Database first approach)

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, ef-database-first

I am trying to use EF6 in my ASP.Net5/MVC6 application, I installed the EF package from Nuget but I am not getting any template to generate the EDMX file (it was possible in previous veriosn of MVC). I found couple of article that talks about code first approach.

But how can I use DB first approach with EF6 and Asp.Net5, because I already have my database design ready. Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

there are some tutorials that you can see in youtube :

[ASP.NET MVC 5 Step by Step: Part 5 Entity Framework Database First](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0Xs33UMLnA)

[Use ASP.NET Identity on existing DB-Model PART 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM)

and [this is one sample](https://github.com/rabbal/AspNetWebForms-Forum) of integration asp.net identity and EF Db First that I developed 2 years ago

you can use following method for generate .EDMX file in code first approach:

```
void ExportMappings(DbContext context, string edmxFile)
{
     var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
     using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(edmxFile, settings))
     {
         System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, writer);
     }
}
```

if your database is already then you can use **Entity Framework Power Tools** for generate domain classes for using EF code First .